# Modelo E.R - Correto?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, entidade-relacionamento

Olá, irei desenvolver um projeto para meu curso de técnico em informática e estou com dificuldade com um Modelo E.R.
É o seguinte, essa é a descrição do projeto, mas vou ignorar os atributos das entidades ok? Somente falarei a participação de cada uma no sistema.

É um sistema de venda de ingressos, onde o usuário poderá se cadastrar e após isso irá entrar no sistema, com seu login e senha.
Ao entrar no sistema, ele terá acesso aos ingressos dele (comprados por ele), aos eventos dele (nesse caso, ele que venderia o ingresso, ele seria o responsável por tal evento) e também poderá alterar seus dados, obviamente.
A compra será feita por cartão (simulação, no caso).
Ele pode comprar vários ingressos e o ingresso pode ser vendido para vários usuários, visto que para um evento pode haver certa quantidade de ingressos.
É basicamente isso. O resto é visual.
O site seria bem parecido com o ingresse.com (não sei se posso colocar links aqui).

Fiz um assim, mas creio que está errado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem onde esta tendo dificuldade. O papel do usuário seria apenas de comprar o ingresso e vender eles e também realizar o evento?

Comment: É que eu queria saber se meu E.R está correto, porque acho que falta alguma coisa aí, talvez uma agregação, não sei. O papel do usuário é de comprar ingressos de um evento ou realizar um evento e vender os ingressos desse evento

Comment: Falta uma entidade responsável por registrar as vendas dos ingressos feita pelo usuário, não se é isso e nem se estou correto. A muita pouca informação aí.

Comment: Vc precisa ser mais especifico neste caso, eu não conheço os requisitos, assim fica difícil afirma se o diagrama esta correto ou incorreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modelo conceitual é o modelo com maior nível de abstração em um Banco de Dados. Por isso, algumas perguntas que parecem simples e lógicas para quem está fazendo acabam se tornando difíceis para quem está lendo. De qualquer forma, vou tentar ajudar com base nas informações apresentadas (tanto no texto, quanto no modelo).

A maior parte do texto descrito não trata exclusivamente de modelagem, mas sim a algo voltado mais para implementação/codificação. Ex: ao entrar no sistema ele terá acesso...; o usuário poderá alterar seus dados...

É importante pegarmos as informações que tratam do relacionamento entre as entidades, assim conseguiríamos os dados necessários para o modelo conceitual. Ex: o usuário pode comprar vários ingressos; os ingressos podem ser vendidos para vários usuários.

Por não termos todas as informações, é impossível precisar se o modelo está certo ou errado (ou se deve ter uma agregação ou não), porém vou realizar a leitura do modelo apresentado, se você perceber alguma informação que não confere com seu sistema, esta parte do modelo precisa ser revista. Os pontos que julgar "interessante" vou chamar de Ponto de Atenção, não necessariamente eles estão certos ou errados, pois dependem do objetivo do seu sistema.

1. Realizar 
   1.1 Um usuário pode realizar muitos eventos.
   1.2 Um evento deve ser realizado por um e apenas um usuário.(ponto de atenção: de acordo com o modelo apresentado, o seu sistema não contempla a realização de um evento por dois usuários ou mais).
2. Possuir
   2.1 Um evento deve possuir muitos ingressos.(ponto de atenção: de acordo com o modelo apresentado, não podemos ter um evento sem que ele possua ingressos).
   2.2 Um ingresso deve ser possuído por um e apenas um evento.
3. Comprar
   3.1 Um usuário pode comprar muitos ingressos.
   3.2 Um ingresso pode ser comprado por muitos usuários.

Acredito que o modelo conceitual, de acordo com o que você informou, também poderá receber o relacionamento Vender, entre as entidades Usuário e Ingresso. Para que uma Agregação seja inserida no modelo, teríamos que alterar não apenas a redação do texto, mas também a lógica que foi apresentada no modelo.

Espero muito ter ajudado, dentro do possível.

Comment: Obrigado, espaireceu muita coisa!

Comment: Excelente! Que bom que ajudou!